# Cordova: Trouble importing Android Downloader_Library into project

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, apk, apk-expansion-files

I'm using Android Studio and I'm close to just canceling the Android version of my app and just sticking with the released iOS version. I need to use an expansion APK and I cannot for the life of me get the downloader_library to import into Android Studio.

I try and run the project and it says it can't find anything from the expansion downloader. I've tried everything I can find on the forums. I've tried bringing into Eclipse and exporting out. I just can't get this to work.

I don't know if I have some kind of fundamental misunderstanding about Android and libraries and modules and things but I'm about ready to give up on this unless someone has an easy way to help me through. This is the very last step. I have the IAB working, the app works on multiple devices, the performance is good, I just can't figure out this splitting of the APK.

Comment: I dont really know how Cordova works, but how are you importing your library? Is it in gradle? If so, can you share your build.gradle file and Android Manifest?

Comment: It is in gradle. When I get home from work I can share.I'm trying to use the wizard to import the downloader_library and it's not working. I see other people importing to Eclipse and exporting it back out and THEN importing with the wizard, but I assume I'm just really missing something.

Comment: Hi, dumb question, I'm still new to this, can I attach the files to this thread or do I need to post them in their entirety in the comment?

Comment: You'll need to copy paste the content. Alternatively, you create a Gist or post a link to your repo if it's public.

Comment: I double checked, I don't have the "downloader_library" in gradle yet or in Android Manifest. Is there a good walkthrough you could point me to on how to manually get it into both? I do have the "zip_file" and "play_licensing" libraries in but they were imported using the wizard.

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with Cordova. I just thought if I could look at your code I may be able to help.